# django-autocomplete-light with crispy forms

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I am trying to implement an autocomplete search on a foreignkey field in my form. I have been through the docs but not sure what I need to do to get it working. I just get the normal dropdown box on the foreignkey field.

Here is my attempt:

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'crispy_forms',
    'autocomplete_light',
)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^autocomplete/', include('autocomplete_light.urls')),
```

models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
    ...

class Branch(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='clients')
    ...
```

forms.py

```
import autocomplete_light

class BranchForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Branch
        autocomplete_fields = ('client')
        exclude = ('creation', 'last_modified')
```

form.html

```
 <form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form|crispy }}
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                            <a href="{% url 'branch' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button></a>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out in the end. Needed to register it.

```
autocomplete_light.register(Branch,
           name = 'ClientAutocomplete',
           choices = Client.objects.all()
       )

       class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
           class Meta:
               model = Client
               exclude = ('creation', 'last_modified')


       class BranchForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):
           class Meta:
               model = Branch
               autocomplete_names = {'client':'ClientAutocomplete'}
               exclude = ('creation', 'last_modified')
```